# Cordova looking for cordova_plugins.js on another folder using SplashScreen plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm using Cordova `4.2.0` and the plugin `org.apache.cordova.splashscreen`.

My Android application runs and the plugin works. However, I can't hide the splash screen from inside my javascript file.

So, this works:

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>
```

This not works:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    //{Angular app creation omitted here}
    setTimeout(function() {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }, 10000);
}
```

I suspect this is happening because Android look for a file that does not exists in the specified folder.

```
02-12 12:09:37.561: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(27796): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/js/cordova_plugins.js
```

In fact the real path of the file is `www/cordova_plugins.js` (inside assets folder on the Android project).

I tried call this file on my `index.html` but another error is thrown (and the application does not starts):

```
02-12 12:16:32.100: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(30211): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/js/plugins/org.apache.cordova.splashscreen/www/splashscreen.js
```

And again the real path has not `js/` prefix.

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue today itself and @rcorreia has answered perfectly.

**cordova.js** and **cordova_plugins.js** should be in the same directory. Once you change the location of cordova.js, it will search in the same directory for the file cordova_plugins.js

If you are using the platform Android, files should be in **YOUR_APP\platforms\android\platform_www**

As suggested here,http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/

*Include ng-cordova.js or ng-cordova.min.js in your index.html file before cordova.js and after your AngularJS / Ionic file (since ngCordova depends on AngularJS).*

**Quicker Solution** : Just Install cordova, it will find and get the files automatically.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova was looking on the wrong folder because my `onDeviceReady` call were done on `js/cordova.js`, my custom file for Cordova things. There is a method on the library `cordova.js` that search the folder of `cordova.js`. The library uses the found folder to load the plugins. As my custom file had the same name, the library thought that the plugins folder was inside the js folder, when it was on root.

Comment: can you please give example